# Stuck after creating the dictionary, any guidance on what to do after?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the question - '''Given a list of strings, create a dictionary, where keys are
the strings and the values are the number of times the corresponding string
repeats in the list. Do not use any additional libraries.

Example:

```
>>> problem1(['Hello', 'Hello', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Home'])
{'Hello': 2, 'Friends': 3, 'Home': 1}
```

This is my code:

```
def problem2(mystrings):
    mydct = {}

    for x in mystrings:

        mydct = [mystrings]

    for  in mydct:

        return mydct


print (problem2(['Hello', 'Hello', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Home']))
```

I need help on how to make the keys into strings and the values into the number of times the string shows up, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `mydct = [mystrings]` - this overwrites `mydct` and turns it into a `list` containing a single item, which clearly is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> l = ['Hello', 'Hello', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Home']
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> c
Counter({'Friends': 3, 'Hello': 2, 'Home': 1})
>>> dict(c)
{'Hello': 2, 'Friends': 3, 'Home': 1}
```

so your function should be like

```py
from collections import Counter

def problem2(mystrings):
    return dict(Counter(mystrings))
```

if for any reasons, you are not allowed `collections.Counter` which is part of the Python's standard library, do the following:

```py
def problem2(mystrings):
    counter = {}
    for word in mystrings:
        counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1

    return counter
```

Comment: One of OP's requirements is "Do not use any additional libraries", which I would guess includes `collections`.  But this is certainly what I would use in "real" code.

Comment: @0x5453, `collections` is part of the standard library, so it doesn't count as an additional library.

Comment: That's up to whoever is judging this assignment.  It's possible that *all* `import`s are off limits.

Comment: @0x5453, I updated my answer in case he is unable to use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 0):

```py
words = ['Hello', 'Hello', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Friends', 'Home']
result = {}

for word in words:
    if word not in result:
        result[word] = 1
    else:
        result[word] += 1
print(result)  # {'Hello': 2, 'Friends': 3, 'Home': 1}
```

Note that we first want to check whether there's a key already in the dictionary because if we just run `result[word] += 1` we'll get a KeyError since there's no key in the dictionary with that name.